# Unable to include relative path file using Jade Template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm receiving the following error when I'm attempting to include a file in the same folder:

```
the "filename" option is required to use "include" with "relative" paths
```

There are two files:

index.jade

list_of_items.jade

```
.content-container
  .row
    .col-lg-10.col-lg-offset-1.col-xs-12
      .row
        .col-xs-3
          include list_of_items
        .col-xs-9
          include content
```

I tried to use base path, but then received the following error:

```
the "basedir" option is required to use "include" with "absolute" paths
```

The code for the base path is as follows:

```
.content-container
  .row
    .col-lg-10.col-lg-offset-1.col-xs-12
      .row
        .col-xs-3
          include /User/project/list_of_items
        .col-xs-9
          include content
```

I'm completely at a loss.  Is there another setting somewhere that I am missing?  It feels like this should be something super simple.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `jade.compile()`, right? As the error message states, you are not passing the `filename` option. Since you are only giving a string to compile to Jade, it does not know where to look for the included files.

An example where the script and the jade files are in the same folder. The `index.jade` file includes another file using `include foo`:

```
var jade = require('jade'),
    fs   = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var fn = jade.compile(fs.readFileSync('index.jade', 'utf-8'), {
  filename: path.join(__dirname, 'index.jade'),
  pretty:   true
});

console.log(fn());
```

Or with "absolute paths" that in Jade are absolute in reference to the given `basedir` you would do the following. The `index.jade` file now includes the same file but using absolute path, ie. `include /foo`:

```
var jade = require('jade'),
    fs   = require('fs');

var fn = jade.compile(fs.readFileSync('index.jade', 'utf-8'), {
  basedir: __dirname,
  pretty:  true
});

console.log(fn());
```

For all options see the [API docs](http://jade-lang.com/api/).

Comment: Completely missed that param and couldn't find any documentation.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Been looking for this answer for hours, could not find how to provide the filename anywhere, this should really be on the official page but it isn't... Many thanks @vesse

Answer (score 0):

You can render dynamic template using function in locales. This method also support filters.

**Jade file**

```
+render('contents/index.md', {filter:'marked'});
```

**Gulp Pipe**

```
.pipe(jade({
  locals: {
    render: function (filePath, options) {
      return jade.render(`include${options.filter ? (':' + options.filter) : ''} ${filePath}`, {
        filename: pathToJadeFileDir + '/something-not_important'
      });
    }
  }
}))
```