# Trouble using "include" with a .pug file

Tags: pug

I am trying to include a simple "footer.pug" file into my "wallet_ui.pug" file in the following file strucutre:

```
/templates
   |-> wallet_ui.pug
   |-> /includes
          |-> footer.pug
```

**wallet_ui.pug:**

[image]

**footer.pug:**

[image]

**ERROR:**

[image]

---

I am using Spring Boot as my main backend.

And I am using the "Sass/Less/Typescript/Jade/Pug Compile Hero" Live Compiler for my .pug files. I have to stress that my .sass files also are having trouble with @import ".." when using this VS Code Extension.

Comment: Is [jade4j](https://github.com/neuland/jade4j) what is doing the compiling?

Comment: @Sean no, I am compiling .pug files to basic .html and using those to render with Spring Boot. I am using the VS Code "Sass/Less/Typescript/Jade/Pug Compile Hero" extension to compile .pug files to .html

Comment: @Sean I feel like I have the same issue & solution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038630/unable-to-include-relative-path-file-using-jade-template), but I how would apply it to pug?

Comment: I would include all the information you can about that extension and a link to it within the question. It seems to be related to that extension rather than something related to Pug itself.

Comment: Ok, will do that now

Comment: You were right, it's an extension issue, as compiling the .pug file manually works perfectly. I will close this questions as it has nothing to do with pug itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the "Sass/Less/Typescript/Jade/Pug Compile-Hero" compilers fault (has a lot of faults now that I look at the github issues). Noting wrong with Pug itself.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know spring but try it this way `include "your path"` maybe it works.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work :/, I tired adding the full file's path but with no success.

Comment: Pug's [include syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) should not be used with quote marks.